# Permissions on sys.syslogins

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, security, permissions

I've got the following scenario:
( loggend in on SQL-Server with full admin-privileges )

Creating LogIn, User, Role and associate them.

```
IF NOT EXISTS( SELECT "name" FROM "master"."dbo"."syslogins" WHERE "name" = 'ocmb_admin' ) BEGIN CREATE LOGIN ocmb_admin WITH PASSWORD = 'pw', CHECK_POLICY = OFF; END

IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM "sys"."database_principals" WHERE "name" = N'ocmb_admin' ) BEGIN CREATE USER ocmb_admin FOR LOGIN ocmb_admin;END

if not exists ( select 1 from "sys"."database_principals" where "name" = N'ocmb_grp_admin' ) begin CREATE role "ocmb_grp_admin"; end

EXECUTE sp_addrolemember N'ocmb_grp_admin', N'ocmb_admin';
```

Works fine. Needed permissions on objects for created login ( `ocmb_admin` ) are granted in separate queries, not completely neccessary for this question.

Now, logging in with this login I have to query `sys.syslogins` which is possible but **only returns data for `current login` and `sa`.**

I tried several ways to grant explicit permissions to the group ( `ocmb_grp_admin` ), but none of them leaded to the fact, that I can query the complete content of the view.

**I need to determine, whether some logins exist while logging in with an random account, which is assigned to the prior created role '`ocmb_grp_admin`'. Permissions can and SOHULD be granted to this role, to avoid having to grant them for each new user.**

What I tried so far:

**A:**

```
USE master
GO
GRANT VIEW ANY DEFINITION TO "<username>"
```

This one works, but is completely uncomfortable, because every user has to be added separately.

**B:**

```
USE master
GO
GRANT VIEW DEFINITION ON master.sys.syslogins TO ocmb_admin
```

Error - Definition privilege is not compatible with object.

**C:**

```
USE master
GO
GRANT VIEW DEFINITION ON master.sys.syslogins TO ocmb_grp_admin
```

Same as B

**D:**

USE master
GO
GRANT VIEW DEFINITION ON LOGIN::ocmb_admin TO ocmb_admin

Can be executed, if `ocmb_admin` is also created on `master`-db, but does not have any effects on querying.

**Thanks for hints!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [SUSER_ID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176042.aspx) which will give you the SID from [sys.server_principals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188786.aspx) regardless of [metadata visibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187113.aspx)

Also note that [syslogins](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178593.aspx) has been deprecated since SQL Server 2005

Comment: Great! Works like a charm! Is there a similar way to retrieve if a role exists? ATM, I access `sys.database_principals`!

Comment: Use DATABASEPRINCIPAL_ID: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187319.aspx